# EF Core 3.0 - System.Linq.Dynamic.Core - Update Linq to work in 3.0 after upgrade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, iqueryable

I have a linq query that doesn't work anymore (since upgrading to core 3.0). 
If I comment out the "if" lines it does work.

If I do just just an `.OrderBy("FromDate")` it breaks because it is creating the following

`(ti => ti.Outer.FromDate.HasValue == True ? ti.Outer.FromDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "")`

and says it can't translate it.

I have a search parameter as well as the column name to sort by.  How can I get around these issues to get it to work in 3.0?

```
  public IQueryable<TimeSheetMasterView> ShowMyApprovedTimeSheet(string sortColumn, string sortColumnDir, string Search, string UserID)
    {
        var iQueryabletimesheet = (from timesheetmaster in _context.Set<TimeSheetMaster>()
                                   join registration in _context.Set<AspNetUsers>() on timesheetmaster.UserId equals registration.Id
                                   where timesheetmaster.TimeSheetStatus == 2 && timesheetmaster.UserId == UserID
                                   select new TimeSheetMasterView
                                   {
                                       TimeSheetStatus = "Approved",
                                       Comment = timesheetmaster.Comment,
                                       TimeSheetMasterID = timesheetmaster.TimeSheetMasterId,
                                       FromDate = timesheetmaster.FromDate.HasValue == true ? timesheetmaster.FromDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "",
                                       ToDate = timesheetmaster.ToDate.HasValue == true ? timesheetmaster.ToDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "",
                                       CreatedOn = timesheetmaster.CreatedOn.HasValue == true ? timesheetmaster.CreatedOn.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "",
                                       TotalHours = timesheetmaster.TotalHours,
                                       Username = registration.Email,
                                       SubmittedMonth = timesheetmaster.ToDate.HasValue == true ? timesheetmaster.ToDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MMM") : "",
                                   }); 


        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
        {
            if (sortColumnDir == "asc")
            {
                iQueryabletimesheet = iQueryabletimesheet.OrderBy(s => s.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(s, null)).ThenBy(o => o.Username).ThenBy(o => o.FromDate);
            }
            else
            {
                iQueryabletimesheet = iQueryabletimesheet.OrderByDescending(s => s.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(s, null)).ThenBy(o => o.Username).ThenBy(o => o.FromDate);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
        {
            iQueryabletimesheet = iQueryabletimesheet.Where(m => EF.Functions.Like(m.Username, $"%{Search}%") || EF.Functions.Like(m.SubmittedMonth, $"%{Search}%") || EF.Functions.Like(m.TimeSheetStatus, $"%{Search}%") || m.ToDate.Contains(Search) || m.FromDate.Contains(Search));
        }
        return iQueryabletimesheet;
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you remove the project (`select new TimeSheetMasterView`) and simply select `timesheetmaster` then order by any field (comment out your other code), does it work fine?

Comment: No, if I remove "new" it says 'TimeSheetMasterView' is a type which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: I meant remove the whole thing and only select the model: `select timesheetmaster`

Comment: It will run fine if I remove all the if statements...  and even if I do an .OrderBy any string value (bombs on a date field)

Comment: I get that and the reason why is because the database cannot translate what you have specified for the `FromDate` on your view projection. Try adding a `ToList()` call to retrieve the data before ordering: `select new TimeSheetMasterView { ... }).ToList()` and you will see that ordering in memory should work fine.

Comment: see now... I didn't think it would do the slightly more complex filtering regardless - but it did.  I would paste the modified code but the comment is limiting me and won't accept it.